# Group Concat the max id in the query

Tags: php, mysql

How can i `group_concat` the selected max id in the query.

**example:**

```
select group_concat(max(id) SEPARATOR ',') from attempts group by user, attempt having count(*) > 1;
```

im having an **error code**

> 1111: invalid use of group function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use a subquery:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id)
FROM
(
    SELECT MAX(id) AS id
    FROM attempts
    GROUP BY user
) t;
```

The subquery finds all max `id` values for users in your table.  Then, we roll them up into a CSV string.  Note that if you wanted only distinct `id` values then you could have done:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT id)
```

Comment: Remember, Group_concat, acutally has a limit on its maximum returned result set. Which I believe is around 1024 results. 
Everything past that point will simply be disregarded.

There is a way to increase the parameter that allows for that number to be increased. But as everything, be careful, as performance takes a hit when you do this. 

You might want to find a different structure to help you get around the usage of that query, or make sure that the possible results are very limited.